# How to retrieve hash value from session in Perl

Tags: perl, mojolicious, strawberry-perl

I am storing a hash in session. I am trying to retrieve the values from session, but is not successful. I want to loop through the hash value in session to generate a select box. Below is the session value

```
$VAR1 = {
          'userDetails' => {
                           'roles' => [
                                      {
                                        'ln' => 'asdf',
                                        'email' => 'test@example.com',
                                        'session_id' => '14',
                                        'is_active' => '0',
                                        'role' => 'ndfbfd',
                                        'facility_name' => 'jjjj',
                                        'fn' => 'yyyyyy'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'ln' => 'asdf',
                                        'email' => 'test@example.com',
                                        'session_id' => '15',
                                        'is_active' => '1',
                                        'role' => 'ndfbfd',
                                        'facility_name' => 'fbhsdf',
                                        'fn' => 'yyyyyy'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'ln' => 'asdf',
                                        'email' => 'test@example.com',
                                        'session_id' => '16',
                                        'is_active' => '1',
                                        'role' => 'ndfbfd',
                                        'facility_name' => 'mvsd',
                                        'fn' => 'yyyyyy'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'ln' => 'asdf',
                                        'email' => 'test@example.com',
                                        'session_id' => '17',
                                        'is_active' => '1',
                                        'role' => 'bdfgre',
                                        'facility_name' => 'jjjj',
                                        'fn' => 'yyyyyy'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'ln' => 'asdf',
                                        'email' => 'test@example.com',
                                        'session_id' => '18',
                                        'is_active' => '0',
                                        'role' => 'gderere',
                                        'facility_name' => 'jjjj',
                                        'fn' => 'yyyyyy'
                                      }
                                    ],
                           'ln' => 'asdf',
                           'logged_in' => '1',
                           'fn' => 'yyyyyy'
                         },
          'logged_in' => '1',
          'username' => 'test@example.com'
        };
```

I am trying to retrieve the roles from the session

```
my %userDetails = $self->session('userDetails');
my %roles = $userDetails{'roles'};
foreach my $family ( keys %roles ) {
    print "$family: { ";
    for my $role ( keys %{ $HoH{$family} } ) {
        print "$role=$HoH{$family}{$role} ";
    }
    print "}\n";
}
```

It is showing two errors.

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected.
Odd number of elements in hash assignment.
```

When I change the code `my %userDetails = $self->session('userDetails');` to `my %userDetails = \$self->session('userDetails');` I am getting the error

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment.
Odd number of elements in hash assignment.
```

Comment: Your code seems completely unrelated to the data that you show and I don't see how it can generate the errors you say it does. `$self->session('userDetails')` returns a hash reference, not a hash, and `roles` is an array, not a hash. There is no mention of `family` in your data, and you never declare or define `%HoH` (which is a lazy name for a variable anyway).

Comment: It is just a variable name. I just copied the foreach code from somewhere. Problem is with lines `my %userDetails = $self->session('userDetails');
my %roles = $userDetails{'roles'};`

Comment: You can't write working code by "copying code from somewhere". You clearly have no idea what you're writing.

Comment: I do have an idea of what I am writing. I am a PHP programmer trying to learn Perl.

Comment: [`perldoc perldsc`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing blatantly

```
my %userDetails = %{$self->session('userDetails')};
my @roles = @{$userDetails{'roles'}};
require Data::Dumper;
foreach my $family ( @roles ) {
    print Data::Dumper::Dumper($family);
}
```

In your example

> 'roles' => [

so this indicates that the value beneath the role attribute is an array reference.

> $self->session('userDetails')

might be hash, or more probably a hash-reference. I guessed the later. So if you have a reference to an "element" you derefence it first. See [perldoc perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't know why getting downvotes when the SO is meant for helping each other.